# Android package name question

Tags: android, package

The package name of each application (both lite and pro version) must be unique.
Can the package name be changed later during development?  Because the package name used in my application can already be used by other applications on the market.
As far as i remember once i modified the package name of my app and it was showing errors everywhere (despite i changed the package name everywhere).
One other thing: as the update of an app is a modified version of it, i guess the package name of the update stays the same of the app’s. Or i could say the package name of the modified app..

I am pretty sure that my answers to my questions are

1. Yes, package name can be changed later (before publishing)
2. During an update the package name should stay the same.

I just want to make sure..

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right about the probable answers.

1. Yes you can and it should work. I haven't seen the error messages you got so I can't tell what was it but you might have forgotten to update the Manifest.
2. Yes. The package package name should stay the same. If you change the package name the application will not be recognized as the same.

From the Android Developer page:

> Before uploading the updated
>   application, be sure that you have
>   incremented the android:versionCode
>   and android:versionName attributes in
>   the  element of the manifest
>   file. Also, the package name must be
>   the same as the existing version and
>   the .apk file must be signed with the
>   same private key. If the package name
>   and signing certificate do not match
>   those of the existing version, Market
>   will consider it a new application,
>   publish it as such, and will not offer
>   it to existing users as an update.

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Comment: Thanks. What is the versionCode and versionName? E.g. from the dev site: android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.1". In this case versionCode means that is an update? So at first the code is "1" and the name is "1.0" then it is "2" and "1.1" then at the second update the code is "3" and the name is "1.2"/"2.0" etc?

Comment: It works just as you said.
The versionCode tells that the new package is more recent than the last one. It's an internal integer value that is not shown to the user but holds the actual versioning control.
The versionName is the version shown to the user. It can be a raw string or a reference to a string value in the resources. It's only purpose is to be shown to the users.

Comment: I maybe found it: e.g. i publish the 8th update of an app. The versionCode is 2.1.5, but the versionName is 8. Is that right? Why is the versionName a string? Just an opportunity? Could you provide me an example when the versionName is a string?

Comment: Didn't you mean the opposite? You're going to public the 8th update of your application: versionCode is 8 and versionName is 2.1.5 .
The versionName can be as string so you can show to your users something like: "2.2a" if you want to show that's an alpha version.
versionCode also doesn't need to be exactly 1+. you could make it: 1st=1 2nd=4 3rd=19 4th=21... The only requirement is for the update to be an integer bigger than the previous release.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, package name can be changed later and may be changed after publishing but its as if you are developing a fully new application.
2. During an update the package name should stay the same